# Python encoding error(it works at one point and then it doesn't...)

Tags: python, pyqt, decode, python-unicode

So, I'm using Python (with PyQt) and I have this strange problem.
In this:

```
self.listwithnames = ["Α.Μ.","Μονομελές-Τριμελές", "Ονοματεπώνυμο","Όνομα Πατρός","Όνομα Μητρός","Ημερομηνία Γέννησης",
                              "Τόπος Γέννησης","Φύλο","Εθνικότητα","Διεύθυνση Κατοικίας","Αστυνομικό Τμήμα",
                              "Τηλέφωνο","Επάγγελμα-Ιδιότητα","Ημερομηνία Δικασίμου","Αριθμός Πινακίου",
                              "Πράξη","Ημερομηνία Τέλεσης","Τόπος Τέλεσης","Ύπαρξη Συνενόχων",
                              "Παραδοχή","Περιγραφή Πράξης","Εμφάνιση","Αναβολή","Απόφαση","Αριθμός Απόφασης",
                              "Ημερομηνία Απόφασης","Παρουσία","Προηγούμενες Αποφάσεις","Υπεύθυνος Επιμελητής", "Σχόλια"]       

        #Επιλογές Αναζήτησης ComboBox:
        self.combobox = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        for i in range(0,28):
            self.combobox.addItem(self.listwithnames[i].decode("utf-8"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.combobox, 0, 1, 1, 1)
```

Here, it works just fine!
But here:

```
l = [1, 8, 19, 20, 22, 27]
        self.list_with_lists = [["Μονομελές", "Τριμελές"], ["Αγόρι", "Κορίτσι"], ["Ναι", "Όχι"], ["Ναι", "Όχι"], ["Πρωτοείσακτος", "Υπότροπος", "Αναβολή"], ["Παρών", "Απών"]]
        if self.combobox.currentIndex() in l:
            for l_ in self.list_with_lists[l.index(self.combobox.currentIndex())]:
                for string in l_:
                    self.combobox2.addItem(string.decode('utf-8'))
```

It just doesn't, and I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

That's strange...

**SOLVED:**

```
This is the final code:
l = [1, 8, 19, 20, 22, 27]
self.list_with_lists = [[u"Μονομελές", u"Τριμελές"], [u"Αγόρι", u"Κορίτσι"], [u"Ναι", u"Όχι"], [u"Ναι", u"Όχι"], [u"Πρωτοείσακτος", u"Υπότροπος", u"Αναβολή"], [u"Παρών", u"Απών"]]
if self.combobox.currentIndex() in l:
    self.combobox2.clear()
    for l_ in self.list_with_lists[l.index(self.combobox.currentIndex())]:
        self.combobox2.addItem(l_)
```

Comment: it's greek to me.... but seriously, you might try not using `string` as a variable name, because it is a protected word in python, it's the name of type!

Comment: That's not the problem, it works fine with latin characters...

Comment: Instead of `for string in l_:` try removing that loop and just doing `l_.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: But l_ is a list, I don't want the list, I want what's in it...

Comment: did you try? `l_` is an item in `self.list_with_lists[index]`, which means `l_` should be one of two words...

Comment: It's very difficult to debug that code if some obvious issues aren't fixed. Except for not using "string" (it doesn't matter it works with latin characters, it's a matter of clarity), you also need to use unicode strings, like u"Μονομελές". The indentation in the pasted material is also erroneous.

Comment: Do you use Python 2 or 3 ? In case of Python 2, maybe you can write: 
`self.list_with_lists = [[u"Μονομελές", u"Τριμελές"], [u"Αγόρι", u"Κορίτσι"], [u"Ναι", u"Όχι"], [u"Ναι", u"Όχι"], [u"Πρωτοείσακτος", u"Υπότροπος", u"Αναβολή"], [u"Παρών", u"Απών"]]` and then do not use the `decode('utf-8')` method ?

Comment: Oups!!! Oh, come on, I can't believe how stupid I was!!! Of course, l_ is not a list, it's a string! Thanks a lot seth, I must be blind or something. And yes, there is something weird with the indentation, but only on StackOverflow, don't know why...

Comment: okay, I will post as an answer, but you should heed Frodon and Antonis Christofides advice as well.

Comment: Yeah, I know, they are right as well, I upvoted their comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of for `string in l_:` try removing that loop and just doing `l_.decode('utf-8')`